# Twitter gem - how to get the latitude and longitude of a tweet?

Tags: ruby, twitter, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-3.2, twitter-gem

How to get the latitude and longitude of a tweet using the Twitter gem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

took me a while to get my head around but like this:

```
Twitter.status(227376948400230400).place.bounding_box.coordinates
```

hope this helps.

Comment: Is "227376948400230400" the id of a tweet?

Comment: Yes that's the ID of a tweet I posted but you can change this to for example user_timeline(username).first which would be a users last tweet.

Comment: Like this? Twitter.status.user_timeline("username").first.place.bounding_box.coordinates

Comment: It doesn't work: `<main>': undefined method `bounding_box' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)

Comment: that tweet doesn't have a place set. Just did some testing if you don't set a location on the tweet .place will return nil making the rest fail.